# RxSwift, MVVM - Cannot implement UITableViewDataSource methods with RxSwift binding

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am implementing a simple UITableView of addresses using RxSwift and MVVM. I have created a binding in my view controller like this.

```
viewModel.addressList.asDriver()
   .drive(tableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier(reusableIdentifier, cellType: SavedAddressTableViewCell.self)) { [weak self] (row, viewModel, cell) in
        self?.setUpAddressCell(cell, row: (row + 1))
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

However, I keep getting this error when I try to open the page in my app.

```
Maybe delegate was already set in `xib` or `storyboard` and now it's being overwritten in code.
```

I Googled and found that I have to set tableView.delegate and tableView.dataSource to nil.

However, there are some UITableViewDataSource methods that I still need, like

```
canEditRowAtIndexPath
commitEditingStyle
```

for deleting addresses.

How should I implement this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.

Use RxDataSources.

https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources

I really didn't want to use a new pod for this, but I couldn't find an alternative solution.

Okay I did find an alternative solution now!

Use

```
tableView.rx_itemDeleted
```

This function is ReactSwift's wrapper for commitEditingStyle (misleading yes!), whatever you would have written in commitEditingStyle you can now write in this function. For canEditRowAtIndexPath, I always wanted to return true, which is the default return value even if I don't write code for that, so I didn't have to implement canEditRowAtIndexPath at all!

Answer (score 1):

Write this line above:

```
tableView.dataSource = nil
```

Comment: Ah no, that won't work. It will you to populate your cells but not help you to implement the delete animation functions I mentioned above.

Comment: Then you'll want to use [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) or check this [rx-example](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/TableViewWithEditingCommands/TableViewWithEditingCommandsViewController.swift)

Comment: Exactly, I couldn't find an alternate solution myself. Thanks man!